# Joining tables in sqlite

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have three table.

Components :

```
id | name | storage | bilance |
   |      |         |         |
```

Shops

```
id | name | price | componentId |
   |      |       |             |
```

and orders

```
id | item | amount | ... |
```

The table of components holds products.
The table of shops holds shops that sell that product

So for example

```
component( 1 , "wheel" , 15 , 15 );
```

and shops that sell wheel

```
Shops(1 , "wheelShopone" , 150 , 1);
Shops(2 , "Shoptwo" , 100 , 1 )
```

Which basicly mean you can buy wheel in more shops e.g 1:n relation

And order contains what to order e.g

```
orders(1 , "wheel" , 5 )
```

What i want to do is to find all elements in Table orders( e.g components) , that are sold in certain shop.

I tried to using join e.g

```
> Select components.name as comp_name , components.id as comp_id ,
> shops.name as shop_name , shops.id as shop_id , orders.item as item ,
> orders.amount as order_amount from components join shops join orders
> WHERE shop_name = some name
```

What i expect it to do is following , imageine table

```
 components                                       shops
 id | name  | storage | bilance |       id | name | price | componentId|
 1  | wheel | 15      | 15      |       1  | One  | 15    |  1          
 2  | mouse | 1       | 1       |       2  | two  | 5     |  1
                                        3  | three| 5     | 2
```

Joining those two tables using

```
> Select components.name as comp_name , components.id as comp_id ,
> shops.name as shop_name , shops.id as shop_id FROM Components join Shops
```

should result in

```
comp_name | comp_id | shop_name | shop_id 
wheel     |  1      | one       | 1
wheel     |  1      | two       | 2
mouse     |  2      | three     | 3
```

and then finally joining with orders e.g

```
id | item  | amount | ... 
1  | wheel | 5      | ...
```

Using as i previously mentioned command

```
> Select components.name as comp_name , components.id as comp_id ,
> shops.name as shop_name , shops.id as shop_id , orders.item as order_item , order.amount as order_amount FROM Components join Shops
> join Orders on components.name = orders.item
```

should result in

```
comp_name | comp_id | shop_name | shop_id | item | amount
wheel     |  1      | one       | 1       | wheel| 5
wheel     |  1      | two       | 2       | wheel| 5
```

But using this command , it just throws random table that is joined what looks like crossjoin because i get hundreds of lines of data.

Is my understanding of joins correct? If no where did i make mistake and how could i make this work? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yoy probably want something like that:

```
SELECT components.name as comp_name,
       components.id as comp_id,
       shops.name as shop_name,
       shops.id as shop_id,
       orders.item as item,
       orders.amount as order_amount
FROM shops JOIN components ON shops.componentId=components.id
           JOIN orders ON components.id=orders.item
WHERE shop_name = some name
```

The main thing you are missing are the join conditions. In general, when you are doing a join, you must specify a conditon that will be used to match the correct rows from the two tables. For example, the condition `shops.componentId=components.id` says match rows from `shops` with rows from `components` where the `componentId` in the same is the same as the `id` of component.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to do a join, you have to tell the database which rows in the two tables match:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Components
JOIN Shops ON Components.id = Shops.componentId;
```

This relationship is not deduced automatically, not even when you have declared foreign key constraints.

Without the join condition, you indeed get a cross join.